# Find & Format Abbreviations, in N++ if possible

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to find all instances of three or more consecutive capital letters in text, and put periods between them. Eg:

POTUS --> P.O.T.U.S

DL --> DL [unchanged}

Mr. --> Mr. [unchanged]

FGB4D --> F.G.B4D

Can this be done in Notepad++ RegEx? Or do I need PHP, Python etc.?

Answer (score 1):

With notepad++:

```
search: (?:\G(?!\A)|\b(?=[A-Z]{3,}))[A-Z](?=[A-Z])\K

replace: .
```

pattern details:

```
(?: # two possible starts:
    \G(?!\A) # contiguous to the previous match (not at the start of the string)
  |          # OR
    \b       # a word boundary (if you don't need you can remove it)
    (?=[A-Z]{3,}) # followed by at least three letters 
)
[A-Z] # a letter
(?=[A-Z]) # followed by an other letter
\K # discards all characters on the left from match result
```

Comment: Also this should work, but needs few more steps: `(?<!\d)\B(?=[A-Z]{2})|(?<=[A-Z]{2})\B(?!\d)` What about `1FGB4D` should be converted to `1F.G.B4D`?

Comment: @Jonny5: Indeed, in the same way I will write it like this: `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z]{2})|(?<=[A-Z]{2})(?=[A-Z])`, the only problem is that you can't know if the uppercase letters are isolated or inside an other "word" (in particular for the begining).

Comment: A small change: (?:\G(?!\A)|\b(?=[A-Z]{2,}))[A-Z](?=[A-Z])\K. Change the {3,} to {2,}. Otherwise the final pair of capitals won't get the period - "POTUS" will become "P.O.T.US".

Comment: @Kapitano: This quantifier is not what you think: https://regex101.com/r/dC6wC0/1